# Select table and replace column by value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I'm trying to achieve a query on my database(MySQL).

For example:

**Table1**

```
id,code,name
1,1,Tom
2,1,Jerry
3,1,Peter
4,2,Charles
```

**Table2**

```
code,name
1,alpha
2,beta
3,gamma
```

I need to select ALL values from table 1 with the maximum code, but replacing that column (table1.code) for the max value code(table2.code) from table2.

**Desidered output**

```
id,code,name
4,3,Charles
```

For select the max value, I know this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE code = (SELECT MAX(code) FROM Table1)
```

How to replace?

```
SELECT REPLACE(Table1.code, SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE code = (SELECT MAX(code) FROM Table1), SELECT code FROM Table2 WHERE code = (SELECT MAX(code) FROM Table2)) * FROM Table1 WHERE code = (SELECT MAX(code) FROM Table1)
```

I'm confused :c
Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're doing.  How are you relating data in table1 to data in table2?  Are just trying select the max id from table1 and the max code from table2?

Comment: Are you trying to actually UPDATE the data, or simply replace it in the output?

Comment: Yes, and replace max code from table2 to the column values of maxcode from table1, please forgive you my horrible english.

Comment: @Dale, 
I want to select the values in that way, then I will INSERT that output in Table1. But do not worry, for now I just need to select the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT Max(code)
        FROM   table2),
       name
FROM   table1 A
WHERE  code = (SELECT Max(code) code
               FROM   table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to replace the values, instead you can select both top values

```
Select Top 1 id, (Select max(code) from table2), name
from Table1 order by code desc
```

If you would like to have ALL max code values you could try

```
SELECT id, (SELECT max(code) from Table2), name
FROM Table1 WHERE code = (select max(code) from Table1)
```

Comment: Well, I don't see what's the difference between my answer and the one marked, but I hope I had helped you.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a subquery to find max(code) from table 2

```
  Select id,(select max(code) from table2), name 
  from table1 order by code desc limit 1
```

if there are more rows which possess the maximume code you can use the code below

```
  Select id,(select max(code) from table2), name 
  from table1 where code = (select max(code) from table1)
```

Comment: @alessadro My code does the same as your accepted answer does, but I posted it earlier, did you try it?

Comment: Yes @Ahmad, I have tryed. And not is the same. Look closely at both codes.

Comment: @alessadro and Ahmad: The code Ahmad first posted does produce the output desired with the *example data* you gave. However, it does not produce the correct result asked for in the question. The sample data and expected results could have made that more clear. Also; the two of you could have been more polite and understanding talking about it.